# Extract month name and year from timestamp to same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, date-conversion

I have a timestamp in the format: July 13, 2020, 6:07 PM

I would like to only keep the month and the year for my records. Ideally in the format: July, 2020

I've attempted the following that creates a column for each:

```
select 
        count(distinct my_id),
        count(distinct my_loc),
        to_char(created_at, 'month'),
        date_part('year', created_at)
from acc_facts
group by created_at
```

The output is something like this (in 4 columns):

```
86 2 may 2,020
```

Could it be possible to get (in 3 columns):

```
86 2 May,2020
```

Comment: `to_char(created_at, 'month yyyy')`?

Comment: dont store dates as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for you:

```
select 
    TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month') AS "Month", 
    TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY') AS "Year", 
    trim(TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month')) || ', ' || trim(TO_CHAR(created_at, 'yyyy')) as mydate   
from acc_facts
```

Result data:

```
January     2022    January, 2022
January     2022    January, 2022
May         2022    May, 2022
March       2022    March, 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trim(TO_CHAR(now(), 'dd')) || ' ' ||
       trim(TO_CHAR(now(), 'Month')) || ' ' ||
       trim(TO_CHAR(now(), 'yyyy')) as mydate;
```

```
Result is like: 26 Jun 2022
```